# Can I get the Original Install Date of the Windows using C++?

Tags: windows, winapi

How can I get the Original Install Date of the Windows using C++? I have checked msdn but I could not find anything related.

```
HKEY hKey;
DWORD buffer;
DWORD  result;
unsigned long type=REG_DWORD;

    result = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion",0,KEY_READ,&hKey);
    if(result == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
           DWORD BufferSize = sizeof(DWORD);
    DWORD dwRet;
    DWORD cbData = 10;
    DWORD lpType;
    wchar_t cbVal[10];
    cout<<"Value before calling RegQueryValueEx is " << cbVal << endl;


   dwRet=    RegQueryValueEx(hKey,L"InstallDate",NULL, &lpType,
      reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(cbVal),&cbData);

           if( dwRet == ERROR_SUCCESS )
      cout<<"Value is " << cbVal << endl;
    else cout<<"RegQueryValueEx failed " << dwRet << endl;

    }
```

Answer (score 6):

You can read the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\InstallDate` registry key and obtain the value. The reading is done by utilizing one of WinAPI's [registry functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724875(v=vs.85).aspx) such as [RegOpenKeyEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724897(v=vs.85).aspx) and [RegQueryValueEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724911(v=vs.85).aspx). The value represents:

> Number of seconds since 01/01/1970 at 00:00:00 AM

Comment: Is this registry key officially documented? If it isn't then this is no more than an implementation detail that can change without prior notice. It may not be available in future versions of the OS, or - worse - hold stale information.

Comment: I have edited my question upon your advice.I tried above code but I can't get install date value always return null or "".Can u help me ?

Answer (score 3):

As Ron described, you can read the `InstallDate` from the Registry, though it is not officially documented. If you want to use an official API, use WMI instead.  The [`Win32_OperatingSystem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239.aspx) class has an `InstallDate` property.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments. I am wondering if you could please let us know if there is any basic winapi to use in c++?